# Server IP Change - Is using Computer Name to point to server advisable?

Tags: asp.net, ip, connection-string, windows-server-2003, windows-server

IP of the DB Server of our application is being changed. All other settings, configurations etc. incl. "Computer Name" will remain same. 
(DB server's OS is Microsoft Windows Server 2003, DB is Microsoft SQL Server 2005. Applications are .NET 2.0 based.)

It requires that intranet applications, websites pointing to that server need to be referred using new IP which is not yet known. The problem is that changing to a new IP will require significant time & client cannot afford down time of more than a few hours.

I learnt that apart from pointing to server using IP, "Computer Name" can also be used. In our case, "Computer Name" will remain same.

**Is it advisable to point using "Computer Name"? Please suggest any other alternatives as well.**

Comment: I was not about where to ask this question - SO seemed best. Please move question if necessary.

Comment: Downvoter - please share the reason for down vote.

Answer (score 2):

For exactly the reasons you describe, hardcoding IP's unless absolutely neccessary is not best practice.  Updating DNS is easy going through every server and config file hoping you remember all of them is not!

Comment: Well, in the application I work in, hardcoding IPs, service URLs in prevalent. So what are the alternatives? Also, please share some links for "Updating DNS" etc. if you can

Comment: Assuming you have Active Directory, a simple websearch will glean many results but I am sure you will have someone at your company that will know this.  If you don't have AD then what I am getting at is the hostname usage not IP.  You mentioned .net apps so there is no app reason why you need to use IP addresses.  Hostname/DNS Name or IP are your two options.  I don't know anything about your network so assuming that you can connect using a hostname from your appbox to your database server then no reason to use IP, but best discuss with your network admin.

Comment: Thanks. If I'm understanding correctly, "ComputerName" ≡ "HostName" (the one we see under Computer Properties in Windows). Now, if I use HostName instead, will it work on IP change as it is or will I need to restart services etc.?

Comment: Correct on the first part.  Its difficult to give you a 100% answer without a total understanding of what you have, but hostname to IP is cached on a machine for DNS.  Without guessing, a restart of app servers wouldn't be a bad thing.  You can of course make the flip from IP to hostname before changing the IP to make sure it works as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure - but will fiddling with "/etc/hosts" work? Can I point existing IP to new IP by mapping in hosts file?